# How do I add the cpprestsdk library in my project using Xcode 8.2.1

Tags: c++, xcode

I am on Mac and a beginner with Xcode and C++. I have installed a library by using `brew install cpprestsdk`. I then set the header search path in Xcode to `/usr/local/Cellar/cpprestsdk/2.9.1/include/cpprest` for both Debug and Release so that auto completion will work.

I'm trying to follow this tutorial https://github.com/Microsoft/cpprestsdk/wiki/Getting-Started-Tutorial so I wrote a small program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <http_client.h>
#include <filestream.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    return 0;
}
```

But when I try run the program I get a "Lexical or Preprocessor Issue" that states `pplx/pplxtasks.h` file not found in `http_client`. Is there a step that I am missing?

Answer (score 2):

I installed using `brew install cpprestsdk`

You need to set your extra header search path to `/usr/local/include`. There will be found both `cpprestsdk` and `pplx` as both peers to one another. Then use this:

`#include <cpprest/http_client.h>`

You will then run into fatal error: 'openssl/conf.h' file not found See https://github.com/Microsoft/cpprestsdk/issues/458

...resulting needing to have header search paths like so:
`/usr/local/include; /usr/local/opt/openssl/include`

and library search paths like so:
`/usr/local/opt/cpprestsdk/lib; /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib; /usr/local/opt/boost/lib`

and extra linker flags like so:
`-lcpprest -lssl -lcrypto -lboost_system -lboost_thread-mt -lboost_chrono-mt`